# "Form" Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-forms-designer

Not sure why I am getting this below error when I tried to set MDIParent of Form2 to Form1.
I have the same code running on`.NetFramewok` but it is not working in `.Net Core 3.1`

appreciate your help and guidance in understanding the bigger picture.

error at *Form2.MdiParent*

> Form2.MdiParent = Me

[image]

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.MdiParent = Me
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2

```
Partial Class Form2
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Text = "Form2"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you declared an actual new instance of the class Form2 called Form2 somewhere?

Comment: That code is nuts. Why are both `Form1` and `Form2` trying to set the `MdiParent` of `Form2`? Did you edit that `InitializeComponent` method yourself?

Comment: @John sorry that was a typo. I removed that line I guess I was testing only. Ths 'InitializeComponent' was auto-generated

Comment: Does `Form2` have a constructor with parameters?

Comment: no constructor in 'Form2', I have a small 3 forms project built-in `.NetFramework` and just rebuilding the code in '.Net' I had no constructor inf From2 under `.NetFramework'

Comment: 'Me.IsMdiContainer = True' --> Form1 Property

Comment: I'm not sure why it's happening if there's no constructor in `Form2`. I just tested the same code and it worked. That said, I would consider it bad code anyway. You're relying on a default instance and I would advise against doing that at all, except maybe when you want a singleton. It would be better to explicitly create an instance of the `Form2` type and set the `MdiParent` of that instance immediately before calling `Show` on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246810/discussion-between-unis-and-john).

Comment: @Jhon have you tried the code in .Net Core Project or .Netframework
It works fine in .NetFramework ! without a constructor. Form2 will be a singleton.

Comment: Tested against .NET 6. Just realised that you are using .NET Core 3.1. I haven't tested but it may not support default instances. Will check.

Comment: Yeah, no default instances in .NET Core 3.1. Either upgrade to .NET 6, which will have a longer support period that .NET Core 3.1, or create all your form instances explicitly. I would recommend the latter regardless of which framework you target. Very few experienced developers use default instances as they are simply not needed. They were added primarily to make those migrating from VB6 feel more at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that .NET Core 3.1 does not support VB default form instances. If you want to stick with that framework, you'll need to create all form instances explicitly, e.g.

```vb
Dim f2 As New Form2 With {.MdiParent = Me}

f2.Show()
```

If you want to keep using default instances then you'll need to upgrade to .NET 6.

To make a form class a singleton, which works similarly to default instances, you do pretty much as you would for any other class. You add a private constructor, so the class can only be created internally, then you add a `Shared` property to expose the one and only instance. In the case of forms, you need to check whether the last instance has been disposed, as that will require a new one to be created:

```vb
Public Class Form2

    Private Shared _instance As Form2

    Private Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As Form2
        Get
            If _instance Is Nothing OrElse _instance.IsDisposed Then
                _instance = New Form2
            End If

            Return _instance
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

You could then do this:

```vb
Form2.Instance.MdiParent = Me
Form2.Instance.Show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Do you know how to creat a singleton of this instance .

Comment: @Jhon Thank you for the edit very much appreciated. I believe I am confused with all the terminologies here between `.Net vs .Net Core’ vs. Net Framework`. Based on my reading `.Net Core` is new and replaces `.Net Framework`! So When you are referring to .Net 6 which one is it? Sorry newbie here

Comment: @Unis, .NET Core was named that to differentiate it from .NET Framework. Now that .NET Framework has been discontinued at version 4.8, there is no longer a need to differentiate, so what was .NET Core is now just .NET. Much like VB 2005 came after VB.NET 2003 (the .NET was dropped) so .NET 5 came after .NET Core 3.1 (the Core was dropped). There was no version 4 because .NET 5 was basically a convergence and extension of .NET Core 3.x and .NET Framework 4.x. It was built on .NET Core but with similar functionality to .NET Framework added.

Comment: thank you very much. Very will understtood now

Answer (score 0):

As to what @John answered above.

It seems `.Net Core 3.1` does not support default Form instance. `.Net Core3.1` shipped with Visual Studio 2019.

But when I downloaded VS 2022 and created a simple .Net Windows From Project targeting `.Net 6`. I was able to call Form2 directly without the need to instantiate an instance of Form2

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        Form2.MdiParent = Me
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Just incase if someone stumbles through the same issue.